# Why the negative root of the initial value problem $′=\frac{2}{(1+2)}$, $(2)=0$ is not valid?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The solution is $x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}$, but the negative root is valid, I searched online and someone says it does not satisfy the initial condition. But why? why the initial condition could not be satisfied?

Thank you!

Comment: is that because the number?

Comment: It's because the solution $y$ has to satisfy the initial conditions. You will find one of the polarities won't satisfy the IC

Answer (score 3):

Solving the ode $$ y' = \frac{2x}{1+2y}$$

we get:

$$ \int1+2y \text{ }dy = \int 2x \text{ }dx$$
$$ y+y^2 = x^2+c$$
plugging in the initial condition we get:

$$ 0+0 = 2^2+c \implies c = -4$$

Solving for y, the final solutions are:

$$ y = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{4x^2-15}}{2}$$.

But the important thing here is to see which of these solutions, $ y = \frac{-1+ \sqrt{4x^2-15}}{2}$ or $ y = \frac{-1- \sqrt{4x^2-15}}{2}$, satisfies the initial condition we have. It is first one (because for the second one, by plugging on $2$ for x and $0$ for y we get $0=-1$ which is not true). Thus the unique solution to the differential equations is:

$$ y = \frac{-1+ \sqrt{4x^2-15}}{2}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y + y^2 = x^2 + c$ on your third line ?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should get
$$
(1+2y(x))^2=4x^2-15
$$
which indeed has two solutions for $x>\frac{\sqrt{15}}2$. You have to select the branch where the initial condition $y(2)=0$ lies on. The other branch gives $y(2)=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that $1+2y)\neq0$, your initial value problems can be expenses as $(1+2y)\dot{y}=2x$, $y(2)=0$. Integrativen over and interval with endpoints $2$ and $x$ you obtain

$$\int^x_2(1+y(s))y'(s)\,ds =\int^x_22s\,ds$$

The right hand side is $x^2-4$;
the left hand side, using the fundamental theorem of caluculus and a change of variables, is

\begin{aligned}
\int^x_2y'(s)\,ds+2\int^x_2y(s)y'(s)\,ds&=y(x)-y(2)+(y^2(x)-y^2(2))\\
&=y(x)+y^2(x)
\end{aligned}

Thus $y(x)$ satisfies
\begin{aligned}
y+y^2=x^2-4
\end{aligned}
Completing the square on the left hand side one gets
$$
\big(y-\frac12\big)^2=x^2-4+\frac14=x^2-\frac{15}{4}$$
The solution 
$$ y_1(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{x^2-\frac{15}{4}}$$
satisfies the initial condition $y(2)=0$; whereas the solution
$$y_2(x)=\frac12+\sqrt{x^2-\frac{15}{4}}$$
does not satisfy the initial condition $y(2)=0$. That is why $y_1$ is the solution (in fact the only one) to the initial value problem.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating the given DE gives
$$ x^2= y+y^2 + c_1= (y+\frac12)^2 + c_2$$

Using initial value given $ x=2, y=0 $ for roots

we get two solutions because the radical produces $\pm$

$$  y=-\dfrac12 \pm \sqrt{x^2-\dfrac{15}{4}}$$

Evaluating at $x=2$ there are two values

$$ y_1= -\frac12+ \frac12 =0  ;\quad y_2=-\frac12- \frac12 =-1;$$

Only the first solution gives two roots at $y=0,\,@ x= \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{2}. $

Comment: Understanding flap  between  b.c and root.